# How do I know the number of iterations an animation(CAKeyFrameAnimation) did on finish when repeatCount is huge_val?

Tags: iphone, cakeyframeanimation

I am working on a car race game where each car runs in a path. Since the race is time based I have the repeatCount set to a bug value. Now the problem is that I cant figure how many laps are completed when race finished (other words how many times the animation repeated). I tried to use the CGIntersectRect for car's frame and some start point in a timer function from its never accurate.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can make use of `Animation Delegates`

> The CAAnimation class provides the means to notify a delegate object
>   when an animation starts and stops.
>
> If an animation has a delegate specified it will receive
>   animationDidStart: message, passing the animation instance that began.
>   When an animation stops the delegate receives an
>   animationDidStop:finished: message, passing the animation instance
>   that stopped and a Boolean indicating whether the animation completed
>   its duration successfully or was stopped manually.

in `animationDidStart:`you can place counter for measuring iteration.on each time calling incrementing this counter will give you the iteration number

Comment: Thanks for the response Ravindra! Sounds like a plan to me. But does animationDidStart get called for every iteration or just in the beginning. If it gets called in the beginning only then may not be of much use. Delegate name suggests that it will get called when it starts and may not be for every iteration. I will give it a shot in next one hour anyways!

Comment: Ravindra, I just confirmed that animationDidStart gets called only in the begining when you add animation to the layer and not for each repeating while it is running.

Answer (score 0):

I could resolve it myself and may not be the best answer.

I user a CaLayer at the start point and checked if the frames of cars and this layer intersect in a timer too. The problem continues with times since it would intersect multiple times gives the width and the hieght of the images and timer frequency. Then I used a flag to count the lap only once when it is intersecting.

-Thanks!